angular monorepo project doesn't recognize library paths
I have created an Angular mono repo project consisting of 3 projects and one library named 'shared'.

"I have created a shared style in the library and I want to add it to the global styles of all my projects.

I tried to define short aliases within my projects
for example in tsconfig.app.json :
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/app",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@shared-lib/*": ["./../../shared/src/lib/*"],
      "@shared-src/*": ["./../../shared/src/*"],
      "@directives/*": ["app/shared/directives/*"],
      "@pipes/*": ["app/shared/pipes/*", "../../shared/src/pipes/*"],
      "@environments/*": ["environments/*"]
    },
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/main.server.ts",
    "server.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}

and in this project I try to add shared style in styles.scss:
@import '@shared-src/scss/shared-styles.scss' 

but when I serve my app got the error:

for more detail:
this is tsconfig.json of workspace:
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}


I assumed you are using NX as monorepo,
In order to use a style from a lib you just need to import the shared style in your angular.json/project.json file of the apps as style propery
"style": [
"apps/project-a/src/style.css",
"libs/shared-layout/src/style.css"
]


I didn't use NX. I just followed https://angular.io/guide/file-structure#multiple-projects

The solution would be the same

but even if I created a component in shared, other components don't recognize it.
I think it doesn't read from tsconfig file

From what I understand, Angular CLI recognizes paths only if they are defined in the tsconfig file of the repository. It seems like each project doesn't read from its own tsconfig file, even though it's configured in the angular.json file.
